# Why in Rails when checkbox saving, just last element saved correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

With Form_for:

```
- @questions.each do |secret_question|      

= f.check_box :question, {multiple: true}, secret_question.id, 0
= f.label     :question, secret_question.body
```

While saving, if I've checked last element - in base saved right value,

but if I've checked others elements (from first till penultimate) - in base saved '0'

What is wrong?
Thank you

**Update1:**
in controller get params:

```
private
def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name,... :secret_question)
end
```

**Update2:**
Result form:

```
<form id="new_contact" class="new_contact" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contacts" enctype="multipart/form-data"

<input type="hidden" value="0" name="contact[secret_question][]"></input>
<input id="secret_question_1" type="checkbox" name="contact[secret_question][]" value="1"></input>
<label for="secret_question_1">1</label>

<input type="hidden" value="0" name="contact[secret_question][]"></input>
<input id="secret_question_2" type="checkbox" name="contact[secret_question][]" value="2"></input>
<label for="secret_question_2">2</label>

<input type="hidden" value="0" name="contact[secret_question][]"></input>
<input id="secret_question_3" type="checkbox" name="contact[secret_question][]" value="3"></input>
<label for="secret_question_3">3</label>

<input type="hidden" value="0" name="contact[secret_question][]"></input>
<input id="secret_question_4" type="checkbox" name="contact[secret_question][]" value="4"></input>
<label for="secret_question_4">4</label>
```

Comment: If you have `secret_question.id`, `secret_question.body`  instead of `question.id`, `question.body` form looks right. Please, show how you get params and html generated by `form_for`.

Comment: And how you save params?

Comment: contact.save  in create method in Contacts controller.

Comment: I mean how you assign params to contact?

Comment: Okey, now I understand. contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

Comment: Would you mind cleaning up your example code a bit? :) The ruby part doesn't seem to work (`secret_question` vs `question`) and the html output doesn't match the ruby code you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your

```
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name,... :secret_question)
end
```

to

```
def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name,... :secret_question => [])
end
```

to declare that parameter should be array.

Comment: Your answer solved the problem with getting all checkbox elements from params, but it still show me the '0', ex. if I choose all checkbox elements(1..4), it save in db the array: ['0', '1', '0', '2', '0', '3', '0', '4', ]. Please, could you tell me why form_for generate hidden fields with value '0' before every checkbox input element. Thank you

Comment: If you write `f.check_box :question, {multiple: true}, question.id, nil` it will not add hidden field

Answer (score 0):

Your input elements have the same `name` attribute: `contact[secret_question][]`. When submitting the form the browser sends all input elements in the order they are found inside the DOM, but Rails takes the last key-value pair it receives, if there are keys with the same name, and saves this value. This behavior conflicts with [the way Rails treats checkboxes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box).

You can either use the option `include_hidden: false` for every `check_box` except of the first or you can use the `check_box_tag` instead of `check_box`. `check_box_tag` won't generate the hidden checkboxes which are causing the trouble.